# Client Server program without using Socket (With PCAP)

Tags: tcl

I have plans do a prototype of client-server program without using socket.The client server should be able to transfer file (only txt file) between client and server and read the file.I am trying in TCL by using the PCAP.dll.Any suggestions for my idea.

The Exact description is transfer of files using link layer protocols. I am using reserved protocol number 253.

For instance i will show how this is implemented with pcap .Here i am able to send data without saving it to link layer .
pcap send $handle " tftp packet data"

Comment: I suppose you are looking for a solution on Windows platform. Is [Raw sockets](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740548(v=vs.85).aspx) what you are looking for?

Comment: @Isaac Can i Transfer data between two link layers.Without use of any socket .

Comment: IP protocol field http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3692 http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv4#Header